# A question regarding a recursively defined sequence: $s_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(s_{n} + \frac{a}{s_{n}})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm reading Sherbert and Bartle's Introduction to Real analysis. In the context of the study of sequences, they give as an example the following sequence, defined recursively by:

$$s_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(s_{n} + \frac{a}{s_{n}}),$$

where $a$ is a positive real number. $s_1$ is defined to be any arbitrary positive number. The purpose is to give an illustration of a sequence that converges to $\sqrt{a}$.

One of the things they show to prove the convergence of this sequence is that it is decreasing for $n \geq2$. To show this, they rewrite the equation above as follows:

$$s_{n}^2-2s_{n}s_{n+1}+a=0.$$

Next, they note the following: "Since $s_n$ satisfies the quadratic equation $s_{n}^2-2s_{n}s_{n+1}+a=0,$ this equation has a real root."

My question is: why does it follows that the equation mentioned has a real root? Because the sequence is defined for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (actually, one can show that $s_{n}$ is strictely positive for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$)?

Comment: The discriminant is $s_{n+1}^2-a$. So the proof should establish that $s_n$ is bounded below by $\sqrt a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s_n$ is the real root mentioned, which is a real number.

Comment: $s_n$ is indeed the real root, such that
$$s_n = \frac{-s_{n+1}+/-\sqrt{4s_{n+1}^2-4a}}{2}$$

Is it because we know that $s_n$ is strictly positive that we can say this equation has a real root?

Comment: $s_n$ is, by construction, a real number, you start knowing that.

Comment: Oh, of course, I see now. Thank you for your help.